# How access HTML5 video methods with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm writing an HTML5 app and I'm trying to access native video methods (play, pause, etc...) and use jQuery. I don't want to use any other plugins.

```
var movie = $('#video_with_controls');

$('#buttonX').click(function() {
            movie.play();
      });
```

But when I execute the preceding code, I get the following console error message:

```
Object has no method 'play'
```

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

HTML5 video DOM element does have [.play()](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#playing-the-media-resource) method. There is no play method in jQuery [yet](http://api.jquery.com/play/).  What you're doing wrong is firing play from a jQuery selector that returns **array** of elements.

For example `$('#clip')` returns `[<video width=​"390" id=​"clip" controls>​…​</video>​]` that actually is an array of one DOM element. To access the actual DOM element you need to address one of array elements by doing something like `$('#clip')[0]`. Now you can tell this DOM element to PLAY.

So just do this:

```
var movie = $('#video_with_controls');

$('#buttonX').click(function() {
            movie[0].play();  //Select a DOM ELEMENT!
      });
```

This is my example:

HTML:

```
 <video width="390" id="clip" controls="">
                    <source src="http://slides.html5rocks.com/src/chrome_japan.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;">                
                  </video>
        <input type="button" id="play" value="PLAY" />
```

jQuery

```
$('#play').click(function(){
    $('#clip')[0].play()
});
```

That works: http://jsbin.com/erekal/3